# On back button, why does Firefox jump straight to my previous scroll positions rather than animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, browser-history, jquery-address

Please visit the demo: http://96.0.13.132

Click around for awhile, now hit the back button. In webkit browsers, you are animated back to the previous "state" while in Firefox you jump back. Why is this? How can I get Firefox to behave more like webkit?

I'm using jQuery, jQuery Address Plugin and jQuery ScrollTo Plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that I was scrolling to pages with an id that matched the hash and the default jump to id behavior was overriding my animations that were bound to the back button.

For example, my link would be to "#about" and I had an element with an id of "about", so Firefox scrolled straight to it before I could animate a scroll to it. Changing the id of the element to "page_about" seemed to fix the problem.

You can see the production site here: http://www.erny.com

Answer (score 0):

Short of [intercepting the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) and then applying the effect you want to achieve with jQuery, this is quite likely "by design" for Firefox, Opera (tested in v11.60 on Windows XP) and .. couldn't test it in Internet Explorer 8 because

```
'console' is undefined in erny.js, Line: 1142
```

which made the browser go to a white screen. It pretty much loaded the page and then immediately broke the site completely. You can fix that by using encapsulating any `console` commands with

```
if (console) { /** your command **/ }
```

which is just good practice because you should *Be Nice To Browsers That Don't Have a Console Or FireBug*™...but then you've also got a very obtrusive `alert` that tells a visitor

> For best viewing experience, please use Firefox, Chrome or Safari

So what I'm building up to saying is that you should focus a little more on just those aspects of the usability of your site first before returning to mostly visual concerns. Unless you're 100% certain that only Safari users will visit your site, you really shouldn't make your visitors feel unwelcome by presenting them with a pop-up or error on their first entry to your site.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. The website is under development. Console logs will be removed before it's made public.

Comment: @curiouser -- Ah, I see. Sorry if I came across as brusque in my answer, I really just wanted to make sure you understand the gravity and effect that the choices you've made so far could have on a visitor, especially if they're a non-developer / IT person. Intercepting the back-button could then be the solution you need for non-Safari browsers.